# How many agents can Java Jade handle?

Tags: java, agents-jade

I'm looking for good practice in MAS, but cant find any on this one :
How many agents should you create with one Java app?

**My example:**

We're making a monitoring software for various hardware and logiciel solutions. One idea was to pop one Jade agent per monitored element. But this may lead us to have more than 500 agents.
Is this an issue?

Performance problems does not count here (actions will be short, rare and not simultaneous).

Answer (score 0):

It will depend on your project and hardware specifications. I can tell you that Jade faces some limitations regarding performance at least comparing to Jason (which is also Java based).

There is a comparison (in just one scenario and conditions) that showed that Jade performance was dramatically affected by the increase of agents and messages. In this study a Contract Net Protocol was implemented in both platforms, the number of agents increased from 5 to 275 which produced from 60 to 121200 messages in this test. After all contracts were done the system just shutdown and the "user time" was taken. Jade varies from 2.5 seconds for 60 messages to 313 seconds for 121200 messages. Jason varies from 0.9 to 34 seconds. So, you can see, at least this case, showed that Jade performance is very lower than Jason. It is explained by the way that Jason deliver messages, just putting in the inbox of destination instead of Jade that makes more processes in each communication.

More details in: http://jasonagents.blogspot.com.br/2018/02/implementando-contract-net-protocol-em.html